# $location.path not navigating propertly within $locationChangeStart callback

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

In order to prevent view changes on a form with edits, I am using $locationChangeStart to intercept the view change.  In that function, I am attempting to use a bootstrap dialog to prompt the user.

It all works ok, until the part where I call $location.path(current) to change the view.  Instead of navigation to the appropriate route, it goes to the default route (the home page).  Why is this?

Here is the code I am using in my controller:

```
function onNavigate() {
var turnOff = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart',
    function (event, current, previous) {
        if (vm.canSave) {
            dialogService.confirmationDialog('Are you sure?', 'You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to abandon your form?')
                .then(function() {
                    turnOff();
                    $location.path(current);
                });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
}
```

In the debugger, the value of current is something like

```
http://localhost:3091/#/participant/24
```

at the $location.path line, however my application ends up at

```
http://localhost:3091/#/
```

Comment: You want to change the same route with refreshed view?

Comment: To a different route, different view. Even though the value above is passed as a parameter to $location.path, it ends up at the default route instead..